# We have a Schengen visa for Italy but can we travel for 1 day to Switzerland?

Tags: schengen-visas, switzerland

Can we travel for 1 day to Switzerland from Italy with our Italian Schengen visa obtained in South Africa? We have a Schengen visa to Italy but want to go for 1 Day to Switzerland, is that possible for us from South Africa?

Comment: Per the linked answer, this is a minor itinerary change and will be of no issue.